# Font awesome icon doesn't display in the nz-th

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

I have the following piece of code:

```
<th [ngSwitch]="sortIcon" nz-th class="centered" (click)="toggleSortOrder()" nzSort="Stopped">Sort
      <i *ngSwitchCase="sortEnum.NoSort" class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-sort"></i>
      <i *ngSwitchCase="sortEnum.Asc" class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-sort-asc"></i>
      <i *ngSwitchCase="sortEnum.Desc" class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-sort-desc"></i>
    </th>

toggleSortOrder() {
    this.sortOrder === 2 ? this.sortOrder = 0 : this.sortOrder++;
    switch (this.sortOrder) {
      case 0:
        this.sortIcon = SortEnum.NoSort;
        return;
      case 1:
        this.sortIcon = SortEnum.Asc;
        return;
      case 2:
        this.sortIcon = SortEnum.Desc;
    }
  }

  sortOrder = 0;
  sortIcon = SortEnum.NoSort;
  sortEnum = SortEnum;

export enum SortEnum {
  NoSort, Asc, Desc
}
```

Obviosly, I want to display sort icon. Somewhy it doesn't display. FA styles are fine - when I test same `<i>` tag in the body of table it displays. Toggling also works. I check in the dev tool:

```
<th _ngcontent-c10="" class="centered" nz-th="" nzsort="Stopped" ng-reflect-ng-switch="2" ng-reflect-nz-sort="Stopped"><a class="sort-link">Sort</a></th>
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the nz-icon directive in the `<i>` tags? For me it only displays my icons when I do that. That's also what it's used in the [customized filter panel demo](https://ng.ant.design/components/table/en), where it's inserted an icon manually.

```
<i nz-icon *ngSwitchCase="sortEnum.NoSort" class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-sort"></i>
<i nz-icon *ngSwitchCase="sortEnum.Asc" class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-sort-asc"></i>
<i nz-icon *ngSwitchCase="sortEnum.Desc" class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-sort-desc"></i>
```